# Flutter GestureDetector onTap not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to make a TextFormField unfocus with a GestureDetector when user taps outside but I can't get it to work. onTap never fires.

```
class EditScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('this does not fire, why???????????');

          // this is my attempt to unfocus textformfield when click away
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                maxLines: null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a `Stack`. There are a few examples of what you're trying to do around SO.

Comment: Try to define a color at background of the stack to make sure you touch it. It may not have been resized as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrap your Scaffold with Gesture Detector and then onTap function:

```
      onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
```

So it will fire everytime you tap the scaffold

Comment: Thanks this works, how would you get it to work only when tapping within scaffold body?

Comment: Because you wrap Scaffold inside Gesture Detector. It's like if you wrap Container Inside Gesture Detector the On Tap function will only work if you tap the Container